# setState not setting some states

Tags: reactjs

Im creating a clock that has minutes and seconds. This is how my component looks like

```
class Time extends React.PureComponent
{

constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = 
        {
            hrs: 0,
            mins: 0,
            secs: 0
        }

        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    }

tick()
    {
        //This increments the minutes
        if(this.state.secs  >= 59)
        {
            this.setState({mins: this.state.mins+1});
            this.setState({secs: 0});
        }
        //This increments the hours
        if(this.state.minutes >= 59)
        {
            this.setState({hrs: this.state.hrs+1});
            this.setState({mins: 0});
        }
        else
        {
            //This increments the seconds
            this.setState({secs: this.state.secs+1});
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.tock = setInterval(()=>
        {
            this.tick();
        }, 1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount()
    {
        clearInterval(this.tock);
    }

     render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Time</h1>
                <section>
                    {this.state.hrs}:{this.state.mins}:{this.state.secs}
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

}

export default Time;
```

The mins do increment to 59 and in turn increment the hrs - then reset to 0. But the secs just keep going and never reset to 0. They do update the mins though. The problem is that they go from 0 to infinity and dont stop counting. How can I make them reset to 0 each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so you cannot ensure all the state updates in the sequence with multiple `setState`. I'd suggest that you should have only one `setState` at the end of that function after all `secs`, `mins`, and `hrs` computed.

*Side note I also fixed your wrong value in `this.state.minutes` to `this.state.mins`.*

```
class Time extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hrs: 0,
      mins: 0,
      secs: 0,
    };

    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
  }

  tick() {
    let { secs, mins, hrs } = this.state;
    
    secs += 1;

    if (secs > 59) {
      mins += 1;
      secs = 0;
    }

    if (mins > 59) {
      hrs += 1;
      mins = 0;
    }

    this.setState({ secs, mins, hrs });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.tock = setInterval(() => {
      this.tick();
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.tock);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Time</h1>
        <section>
          {this.state.hrs}:{this.state.mins}:{this.state.secs}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a functional based component to achieve the same effect.

```js
function Time() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState({
    secs: 50,
    mins: 58,
    hrs: 0
  });

  const tick = () => {
    setTime(prevState => ({...prevState, secs: prevState.secs + 1}));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      tick()
    }, 1000)
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(time.secs > 59) {
      setTime(prevState => ({ ...prevState, secs: 0, mins: prevState.mins + 1 }));
    }
  }, [time.secs])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (time.mins > 59) {
      setTime(prevState => ({ ...prevState, mins: 0, hrs: prevState.hrs + 1 }));
    }
  }, [time.mins])

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Time</h1>
        <section>
          {time.hrs}:{time.mins}:{time.secs}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  
}

export default Time;
```